# POSIX Programmer's Manual vs Linux Programmer's Manual

Tags: man

I wanted to take a look at the manpage of `pthread_mutex_trylock`.

By typing `man pthread_mutex_trylock`, I got `No manual entry for pthread_mutex_trylock`.

Then I saw a post suggest doing `sudo apt-get install manpages-posix manpages-posix-dev`.

After that I see description like:

```
PTHREAD_MUTEX_LOCK(3POSIX)                               POSIX Programmer's Manual                              PTHREAD_MUTEX_LOCK(3POSIX)

PROLOG
       This manual page is part of the POSIX Programmer's Manual.  The Linux implementation of this interface may differ (consult the cor‐
       responding Linux manual page for details of Linux behavior), or the interface may not be implemented on Linux.
```

1. What's the difference between this *POSIX Programmer's Manual* and the *Linux Programmer's Manual* that I usually see?
2. What does it mean by saying:

> The Linux implementation of this interface may differ (consult the
>   cor‐responding Linux manual page for details of Linux behavior), or the interface may not be implemented on Linux.

So where  can I find the **manpage** for *The Linux implementation of* `pthread_mutex_trylock` ? Can I use `pthread_mutex_trylock` on my system ? I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: Why downvoted? This is a fairly reasonable question. At least I didn't know I should *install the the manual for the library that implements the interface.* before someone told me so.

Comment: Many thanks to @Kusalananda resolving my confusion. See discussion from https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191520/room-for-rick-and-kusalananda, hope that also help you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It says that because there's no guarantee that the POSIX manuals (for *anything*) corresponds to the actual implementation of the corresponding thing on your particular system.

To get the manual for `pthread_mutex_trylock()`, install the the manual for the library that implements the interface.

On Ubuntu systems, the required manual seems to be part of the `glibc-doc` package (found by searching for the function name on [the Ubuntu package search pages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/)).

The POSIX manual are *definitely not* useless.  The local Linux interface *should* be compatible with the interface described in the POSIX manual, but the implementation-specific manual may also mentions caveats and Linux-specific implementation details and extensions, and similar non-POSIX functions.

The POSIX manuals becomes extra important if you are concerned about the *portability* of your code to other Unix systems, in which case you would want to *avoid* relying on Linux-specific extensions to the POSIX specification.

Comment: Another question, why `pthread_create` is included in the *Linux Programmer's Manual*, while some other like `pthread_mutex_lock` is not? Why?

Comment: @Rick the glibc manpages include one for `pthread_mutex_lock`: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man3/pthread_mutex_lock.3.html

Comment: @Rick  The manual for `pthread_create()` seems to be included in `manpages-dev`. I don't know why the manuals are divided between the packages in this way.

Comment: So the `posix manual` is the standard manual, while the `glibc-doc` and `Linux Programmer's Manual` is the `implementation manual` ? So when I checking the usage by `man 3 printf` on Ubuntu, I am checking the `GNU C (glibc)`'s documentation, not the standard like from `cppference`.

Comment: @Rick cppreference isn't official. It's community maintained (pretty good, but still not officially maintained by the standards body)

Answer (score 2):

As of Arch Linux, the package is `man-pages` from `core`. Take `fcntl` for example, after installing `man-pages`, `man 2 fcntl` gives the Linux Programmer's Manual page while `man 3 fcntl` and `man fcntl` gives the POSIX Programmer's Manual.